# how to designate Cassandra data storage to certain file-system partition?

Tags: cassandra

I used Cassandra to store my data. I use Centos.
   The data seems always to be stored in the root partition, which is too small.
   My file system partitions like

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   25G   26G  49% /
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G   17M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                494M  177M  318M  36% /boot
/dev/sda1                200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home  873G   66G  807G   8% /home
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1001
```

Obviously the root partition (50 GB) is much smaller than one at home (873GB).
   Is there a way that I change a setup to enforce data storage using the 
   partition "/dev/mapper/centos-home" ?

I need to use the command "sudo service cassandra start" to activate Cassandra.
   If without sudo, my authority doesn't allow me to activate Cassandra.

Thanks!

Comment: you can change data directory in `cassandra.yaml` file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit the `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml` file (sometimes it is
   located under `/etc/cassandra` also, depending on how you install
   Cassandra)
2. Update the following properties

   1. (**only available since Cassandra 3.x**) hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints *// put your own directory here*
   2. data_file_directories:  *//put a list of directories here*

      - /var/lib/cassandra/data
   3. commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog *// put your own directory here*
   4. saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches *// put your
      own directory here*

Comment: Beware that the commit log directory requires several GB of space.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed cassandra.yaml under both folders. But Do I need "//"?  like my directory is "/home/Hsiang/cassandraData", so I put "// /home/hhhung/cassandraData". After I changed both yaml, I no longer use "sudo service cassandra start" to activate my cassandra!

Comment: BY the way, after I deleted the tables from Cassandra, the data are still in /var/lib/cassandra/data/, which occupied space. Can I directly delete the folders? Thanks again!