# My Cassandra cannot be activated

Tags: cassandra, centos

I followed the suggested way to change the directory to store my 
   Cassandra data in my personal folder, see: 
  [how to designate Cassandra data storage to certain file-system partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964466/how-to-designate-cassandra-data-storage-to-certain-file-system-partition/35970754#35970754)

I edited the file: `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml` as

```
 1. data_file_directories: /home/hsiang/cassandraData
          . /var/lib/cassandra/data

 2. commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog  /home/hsiang/cassandraData

 3. saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches 
     /home/hsiang/cassandraData
```

but now `sudo service cassandra start` is not going to activate Cassandra.
  What's wrong with that?

a ton of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check cassandra.log & system.log to see, what is the exact issue you are having.
If you don't know where are those use `sudo find / -name "cassandra.log"`

Can be n number of things.

1. Directories you specified must be created. Sometimes cassandra cannot create directories on it own.
2. Can be permission issue on directory

Comment: Thanks! now my Cassandra can start. But it doesn't actually store data in the folder I want. What's still wrong with that?

Comment: What does the cassandra system log say? If you don't know where it is find it and read why it is not writing to your new folders. Also who owns the new folders you're trying to use?